# Pipe creation through functions

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I was wondering if someone can help me modify my current code....

Currently it creates my process using fork() and takes a pointer to a function which executes that childs code block.

I wanted to play around with pipes and attempt to now have Process Y send its pid to Process X and then i want to send it back to the Main...

Heres what i have currently

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void processX();
void processY();

pid_t addChild(void (*childPtr) (), int fileDes[2]) {
    pid_t cpid;
    if((cpid=fork()) == 0) {
        pipe(fileDes);
        childPtr(fileDes);
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else if (cpid < 0) {
        printf("failed to fork");
        exit(1);
    } else {

    }
    return cpid;
}

void processY(int fileDes[2]) {
    printf("Child Y[%d] Created of Parent X[%d]\n", getpid(), getppid());
    printf("We are now going to write Y PID to process X\n");
    pid_t a = getpid();
    char buf[1024]; // child reads from pipe() to buffer
    close(fileDes[0]); // close reading end of the pipe
    write(fileDes[1], &a, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int));

}

void processX(int fileDes[2]) {
    printf("Child X[%d] Created of parent Main[%d]\n", getpid(), getppid());
    int status;

    pid_t Y = addChild(processY, fileDes);
    wait(&status);

    pid_t new_val = 5;
    close(fileDes[1]); // closing the writing end of the pipe.
    read(fileDes[0], &new_val, sizeof(new_val));
    printf("Message read with number %d: \n", new_val);

}


int main() {
    int status;
    int fd[2];
    printf("Main process[%d]\n", getpid());
    pid_t root = addChild(processX, fd);
    wait(&status);
    printf("We are going to read from X to Main and then return the Value we got from Y\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know to create a pipe from Y - X and then X - Main....

Y---->send pid ----> X received Y pid ----- send new info to main --->Main print received data...

Comment: You're missing a call to [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

Comment: i understand that... my question is how can i create the 2 pipes needed..basically where would i create them and how would i pass the fd, the pid_t and its size basically...would it be through my addChild function or the child functions...?? or should i create a sender/reciever method which points to a fd[2] and read the int that being sent hmmm... im confused.

Comment: Updated the original code...

Comment: What does "read A to B" mean?

Comment: What do you mean A to B? I am trying to get my ProcessY to send its pids to ProcessX (creating a pipe from process y to b) and then i want to send a pipe from x back to main...

Comment: I added a small example of what i am trying to achieve...

Comment: I updated my code...

Comment: you should call pipe before forking since PCB (process control block) is being copied including file descriptors https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/

Answer (score 0):

My answer i came up with

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void processX();
void processY();

pid_t addChild(void (*childPtr) (), int fileDes[2], int backToMainFd[2]) {
    pid_t cpid;
    if(childPtr != *processX //prevents the the pipe from main to x from recreating
        pipe(fileDes);

    if((cpid=fork()) == 0) {
        if(childPtr == *processX) {
            childPtr(fileDes, backToMainFd);
        } else {
            childPtr(fileDes);
        }
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    } else if (cpid < 0) {
        printf("failed to fork");
        exit(1);
    } else {

    }
    return cpid;
}

void processY(int fileDes[2]) {
    printf("[PROCESS Y]: Child Y[%d] Created of Parent X[%d]\n", getpid(), getppid());
    pid_t a = getpid();
    char buf[1024]; // child reads from pipe() to buffer
    close(fileDes[0]); // close reading end of the pipe
    write(fileDes[1], &a, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int));

}

void processX(int fileDes[2], int BackToMainFd[2]) {
    printf("[PROCESS X]: Child X[%d] Created of parent Main[%d]\n", getpid(), getppid());
    int status;

    pid_t Y = addChild(processY, fileDes, NULL);
    wait(&status);

    pid_t new_val = 5;
    close(fileDes[1]); // closing the writing end of the pipe.
    read(fileDes[0], &new_val, sizeof(new_val));
    printf("[PROCESS X]: We got Ys' PID as:%d from [PROCESS Y]\n", new_val);

    close(BackToMainFd[0]); // close reading end of the pipe
    char buf[1024]; // child reads from pipe() to buffer
    write(BackToMainFd[1], &new_val, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(pid_t));

}


int main() {
    int status;
    int fd[2];
    int backToMainFD[2];
    printf("Main process[%d]\n", getpid());
    pipe(backToMainFD);
    pid_t root = addChild(processX, fd, backToMainFD);
    wait(&status);

    pid_t new_val = 5;
    close(backToMainFD[1]); // closing the writing end of the pipe.
    read(backToMainFD[0], &new_val, sizeof(new_val));
    printf("[MAIN]: We got Ys' PID as:%d from [PROCESS X]\n", new_val);
    printf("Send sig kills too Y and root\n");
    kill(new_val, SIGKILL);
    kill(root, SIGKILL);
    printf("Terminate program.\n");
    return 0;
}
```